# How to create a custom template for WCSF (.NET 2.0)?

Tags: templates, wcsf

I'm new to the WCSF and can't seem to find anything related to "building a custom template" for creating the views/presenters/code-behinds/etc with your own flavor ...

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

you can find useful information about how to modifying the guidance package in the [Modifying the Guidance Package](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc304884.aspx) topic of the [WCSF Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb264518.aspx). There you will find guidelines about how to create/update templates.

Let me know if this helps,

Ezequiel Jadib

http://blogs.southworks.net/ejadib

Answer (score 1):

Default Install Location to T4 templates can be found here
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Web Client Factory\WCSF Guidance Package\Templates\T4\

Comment: Sorry, that is an old install. I just realized that the October 2007 update is located here (on my machine, anyways. Just check to see where your guidance package is installed) 

C:\Program Files\Web Client Guidance October 2007\WCSF Guidance Package\Templates\T4